# Dockerized project doesn't show changes in browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, containers

I dockerized my react app using these commands:

```
docker build -t image-name .

docker run -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true -v %cd%\src:/app/src -p 3000:3000 --name container-name image-name
```

The problem is that when I save any updates in my components, they do not show up in the browser, although they have been updated in `/app/src`.

I thought that `-e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` would fix it, but it didn't.

When I go to: `docker exec -it container-name bash`. I can see that everything saves correctly, but the changes don't show up in the browser after `ctrl + s`.

When I open `localhost:3000`, there is a popup `Compiled with problems` beacause I have some typescript warnings, but when I close it the website works great, but without updates.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

.dockerignore:

```
node_modules
Dockerfile
.git
.gitignore
.dockerignore
.env
```

Docker logs:

```
(node:26) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:26) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
```

NODE_VERSION
19.0.1

Comment: Not sure what the `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` option does, but have you tried to stopping/removing the old container after re-building and running the new one ?

Comment: But I don't want to make a new container every time when I change something in code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. You need to update this line in package.json in `scripts/start`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "WATCHPACK_POLLING=true react-scripts start",
  },
```

but if You have a big frontend the updating delay will be terrible (like few seconds for every save and update)

Answer (score -1):

I think your build is still old one.
You need to maybe delete in Docker UI old build and run new build and then run that docker image.